# Word macro for reformatting an index entry

Tags: vba, indexing, ms-word

I have a *Word* document using font size 8 in which I manually have created some index objects using the shortcut Shift-Alt-X. It might look like this, showing formatting symbols:

some·words·in·**bold{**·XE·"**bold**"**}**,·some·in·*italic{*·XE·"*italic*"*}*

Actually, the "XE" is set with font size 11 (my normal standard), but I can't reproduce that here. So I have written a macro which intends to normalize the index object when called from just after the ”}”-sign. It extends the range backwards to include the ”{”-sign and resets the selection to standard values:

```
Private Sub NormalizeEntry()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Selection.Range
    With rng
        .MoveStartUntil Cset:="{", Count:=-100
        .MoveStart Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=-1
        .Select
        .Font.Size = 8
        .Font.ColorIndex = wdBlack
        .Font.Bold = False
        .Font.Italic = False
        .Select
    End With
End Sub
```

The macro works fine if I apply it after a standard sequence of words enclosed in brackets like

Behold, {here are some **words** *enclosed* in brackets} and more words...

("brackets" written with a colored font, which I also can't reproduce here), but it fails when used after an XE-entry. The entry gets selectet all right, but the font is not changed. What am I missing here?

Comment: These are the type of problems you get in Word when using local formatting (select text, change font size, etc.) instead of styles. If the document uses 8 point text, create a body text style (most often Normal) that is 8pt and apply it to all relevant text. If you create an XE field and the font size changes, reapply the style, or remove the local formatting that creates the larger font.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. This indeed removes the font problem, but the trouble with bold or italic remains. Also, why does the macro work for body text, but not for the XE-fields?

Answer (score 0):

As John advises, you should set the font attributes of the underlying Style to 8pt. As for the bold & italic formatting:

- Bold should be applied via the Strong character Style; and
- Italic should be applied via the Emphasis character Style.

To revert anything with the wrong format to that of the underlying paragraph Style, simply select the offending content and press Ctrl-Space.

Here's a way of achieving the same thing for all fields via a macro:

```
Sub FieldReset()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Fld As Field, Rng As Range
For Each Fld In ActiveDocument.Fields
  With Fld
    Set Rng = .Code
    With Rng
      With .Duplicate
        Do While .Fields.Count = 0
          .Start = .Start - 1
        Loop
        Rng.Start = .Start + 1
      End With
      Do While .Fields.Count = 0
        .End = .End + 1
      Loop
      .Start = .Start - 1
      .Font.Reset
    End With
  End With
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Macropod, for your input. However your solution is not what I am looking for, I want to format the field upon insertion.

By experimenting I found a useful solution: Don’t use ActiveDocument.Indexes.MarkEntry, but construct the XE-field yourself using rng.Fields.Add. Here is my result:

```
Sub TextToNormal(rng As Range)
    With rng.Font
        .Bold = False
        .Italic = False
        .Underline = wdUnderlineNone
        .StrikeThrough = False
        .DoubleStrikeThrough = False
        .Color = wdColorAutomatic
        .Engrave = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
    End With
End Sub

Function SkipSurroundingSpaces(rng As Range) As Range
    With rng
        .MoveStartWhile Cset:=" ", Count:=wdForward
        .MoveEndWhile Cset:=" ", Count:=wdBackward
        .Select
    End With
End Function

Sub TestSkipSurroundingSpaces()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Selection.Range
    SkipSurroundingSpaces rng
End Sub

Sub InsertXEfield()
    Dim Xref As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Selection.Range
    With rng
        SkipSurroundingSpaces rng
        Xref = .Text
        .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        .Fields.Add Range:=rng, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, _
            PreserveFormatting:=False
        .Select
        .MoveEnd Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=4
        Debug.Print .Start, .End
        TextToNormal rng
        .MoveStart Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=2
        Debug.Print .Start, .End
        .Collapse wdCollapseStart
        .InsertAfter "XE """ & Xref & """"
        .MoveStart Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=4
        .MoveEnd Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=-1
        .Italic = True
        .Bold = True
        .Font.ColorIndex = wdViolet
    End With
End Sub
```

**Comments**:

When selecting a word the range could include a trailing space. This is removed by a call to SkipSurroundingSpaces. Next the selected word is read (actually I take Xref from a form’s inputbox, where it can be changed to something more appropriate, say changing “exoplanets” to “exoplanet”). The range is collapsed to its end and an empty field is inserted. This field might have inherrited formatting from the entry, so it is set back to normal by calling TextToNormal. Then the range is moved into the field (passing by “{·”) and the XE-text is inserted. Finally the range is reduced to include the inserted word only and this word can now be formatted to your heart’s content or as instructed by information from a user form.

(Code and comments updated 2022-06-08)